# How to upgrade a parser of codemirror V 0.92 to be compatible with codemirro V4.4?

Tags: parsing, codemirror

I want to update the freemarker parser present in V 0.92 to be compatible with V4.4. I want to know the changes that need to be made so that it is able to recognize the elements of Freemarker.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rewrite it. Both the API parsers are written against and the general structure of parser is very different from 2.x up. You will probably be able to reuse some internal functions and concepts, but the parser state is not a first-class object, rather than  a closure, and the character stream API is very different.

Comment: It's really great to get a reply from the writer himself. Thank you for that. Is there any reference OOTB that is available that can be used for this mode? I am asking this as it will save me a lot of time else I will be writing the mode from start.

Comment: I am not aware of freemarker mode written for 2-4.x.